# News-reading application using the Observer pattern

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, interview-questions

I have found this question online from an Amazon interview:

> Design a kind of Kindle Fire application where we can subscribe to a news
>   channel and read the news from all publishers as a digital format.

I thought that using the Observer design pattern would be a good solution here.

Here is my implementation:

**`UnitTest` class**

```
[TestClass]
    public class ObserverPatternTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            NewsChannel pub1 = new NewsChannel();
            NewsChannel pub2 = new NewsChannel();

            KindleApplication app = new KindleApplication();
            pub1.Subscribe(app);
            pub2.Subscribe(app);
            string tempStory = "story start";

            pub1.NewStory= tempStory;
            Assert.AreEqual(tempStory, app.Message);
            tempStory = " story b";
            pub1.NewStory = tempStory;
            Assert.AreEqual(tempStory, app.Message);
            tempStory = "story pub2";
            pub2.NewStory = tempStory;
            Assert.AreEqual(tempStory, app.Message);
        }
    }
```

**`KindleApplication` class (Observer)**

```
  public class KindleApplication : ObserverBase
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public override void Update(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }

   public abstract class ObserverBase
    {
       public abstract void Update(string message);
    }
```

**`NewsChannel` class**

```
 public class NewsChannel : publisher
    {
        private string _newStory;

        // Gets or sets subject state
        public string NewStory
        {
            get { return _newStory; }
            set { 
                _newStory = value;
                Notify(_newStory);
            }
        }
    }
```

**`Publisher` class**

```
 public abstract class publisher
    {
        private List<ObserverBase> _observerList;

        public publisher()
        {
            _observerList = new List<ObserverBase>();
        }
        public void Subscribe(ObserverBase app)
        {
            _observerList.Add(app);
        }
        public void Unsubscribe(ObserverBase app)
        {
            _observerList.Remove(app);
        }
        public void Notify(string message)
        {
            foreach (var obesever in _observerList)
            {
                obesever.Update(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general your implementation is fine. You could however use the intefaces that are already provided by .NET:

- [`IObservable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=netframework-4.7)

  > Defines a provider for push-based notification.
- [`IObserver<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobserver-1?view=netframework-4.7)

  > Provides a mechanism for receiving push-based notifications.

You can read more about them in the article about the [Observer Design Pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern)

---

In your your application you could use them to replace the `Publisher` and the `ObserverBase`.

The `KindleApplication` would become a `IObserver<T>`:

```
public partial class KindleApplication<T>
{
    public T Message { get; set; }

    public void Subscribe(IObservable<T> news)
    {
        _newsUnsubscribers[news] = news.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(IObservable<T> news)
    {
        if (_newsUnsubscribers.TryGetValue(news, out var newsUnsubscriber))
        {
            newsUnsubscriber.Dispose();
            _newsUnsubscribers.Remove(news);
        }
    }   
}
```

and it would implement this interface by storing the observables in a dictionary so that you can unsubscribe again:

```
public partial class KindleApplication<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<IObservable<T>, IDisposable> _newsUnsubscribers = new Dictionary<IObservable<T>, IDisposable>();

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        Message = value;
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

The `NewsChannel` is now an `IObservable<T>` that notifies all observers about the changes:

```
public partial class NewsChannel<T>
{
    private T _newStory;

    public T NewStory
    {
        get { return _newStory; }
        set
        {
            _newStory = value;
            Notify();
        }
    }

    private void Notify()
    {
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            observer.OnNext(_newStory);
        }
    }
}
```

The new implementation could use an `ISet<IObserver<T>>` so that you don't subscribe the same channel multiple times and consequently get multiple updates for the same change.

It uses a private class that implements the logic for unsubscribing via the `IDisposable` interface.

```
public partial class NewsChannel<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private ISet<IObserver<T>> _observers = new HashSet<IObserver<T>>();    

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        _observers.Add(observer);
        return new Unsubscriber(_observers, observer);
    }

    private class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
    {
        private ISet<IObserver<T>> _observers = new HashSet<IObserver<T>>();

        private IObserver<T> _observer;

        public Unsubscriber(ISet<IObserver<T>> observers, IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            _observers = observers;
            _observer = observer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _observers.Remove(_observer);
        }
    }
}
```

If you like you can split each class into multipe `partial` files to better separate the implementation of the intefaces from the actual data.

---

As far as the test is concerned it's really hard to follow it. You should split it into multiple tests that possibly verify only a single case. This means you could have such test as:

- `OnNext_NotSubscribed_DoesNotReciveMessage`
- `OnNext_SubscribedToOneFeed_RecivesSingleMessage`
- `OnNext_SubscribedToTwoFeeds_RecivesMultipleMessages`
- `OnNext_SubscribedAndUnsubscribed_DoesNotReciveMessages`
- etc.